# MonoDroid & Adding Licensing to Your App

Tags: licensing, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to add Licensing to my app, and found this article:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html

Is there a tutorial, example etc to do this with MonoDroid? There is no mention on the xamarin website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW**

This library has been moved to:
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/GoogleAndroidVending

It is also no longer a C# port, but the official build from the SDK manager.

These docs are a bit old, but i cover everything:

- https://dotnetdevaddict.co.za/2014/12/19/play-licensing-in-xamarin-android/
- https://dotnetdevaddict.co.za/2014/12/21/downloading-expansion-files-in-xamarin-android/

**ORIGINAL**

I have created the C# version of the licensing library. I am currently using it in one of my apps on Play.
Check out my repo:

[Android.Play.ExpansionLibrary](https://github.com/mattleibow/Android.Play.ExpansionLibrary)

It has a couple of samples, including a simple licensing sample and a expansion file sample. Let me know how it goes.

I know that a guy at Xamarin is working on a tutorial now, but maybe you could put a request for it sooner.

Comment: Hi Mathew! I'm trying to use your library... but I'm experiencing some strange issues on the response codes... can you check out my post to see if you can light my way please.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233213/xamarin-google-licensing-response-mixed-up

Comment: I updated the issue with the new version and some docs. It should give a walkthrough.

Comment: I am going to create a new set of docs in the xamarin repo. Hopefully this will cover most cases.

Comment: A full-on, official walkthrough: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/GoogleAndroidVending